# How to edit the messaging menu?

Tags: 11.10, messaging-menu

I want to remove the Evolution group and replace it with ThunderBird, remove Chat and replace it with Pidgin, and finally remove the Broadcast group.

How do I do that?

[image: messagin_menu screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There is a fantastic article [here](http://lifehacker.com/5703681/remove-unwanted-entries-from-ubuntus-messaging-menu) on how to remove unwanted entries from the menu. I'll give you a short summary of it, but it's worth a full read.

You'll want to run these in Terminal:

`mkdir -p ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist/`

`ln -s /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/evolution ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist/evolution`

`ln -s /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/empathy ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist/empathy`

`ln -s /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/gwibber.indicator ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist/gwibber.indicator`

This will remove CHAT, BROADCAST, and EVOLUTION from the menu. I can't tell you how to install the Thunderbird one, however; this command MAY do it, but there's no promises. I don't use Thunderbird, so I can't give an absolute answer.

`sudo cp /usr/share/applications/thunderbird /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/thunderbird`